# joining tables with many possible columns to be included

Tags: mysql, sql

i had a hard time figuring out title for this question.

lets say we have three tables that we want to join together USERS, SETTINGS and ADMINS:

```
SELECT 
users.name AS name, 
users.registered_date AS date FROM users 
LEFT JOIN settings ON users.id = settings.user_id 
WHERE users.id IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
users.name AS name, 
admin.registered_date AS date
FROM admins 
LEFT JOIN users ON admins.user_id = users.id 
WHERE admins.is IS NOT NULL
AS USERS;
```

This is going to present data from users joined with settings and admins joined with users AS USERS. But what happens when given admin doesnt have a referenced user? i assume the name will be null then but what do i do if i want another value in this place. my logic is:

```
i want the name to be users name if the user exists, if it doesnt i want it to be one of the admins column?
```

Is it possible to achieve inside this query?
(is the question clear?:])

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: can you provide me with the literal example for this case?:)

Comment: Is Settings your main file where user_id might be either the key of the users table or the admins table?